# Why I'm not getting the text in div?

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need the 'Taxa DI' value that is at the top of [this website](http://www.b3.com.br/pt_br/). I'm currently using the following script to get it and it's working as intended.

```
def get_TAXA_DI():
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
    
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('headless')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver.exe', options=options)
    driver.get('http://www.b3.com.br/pt_br/')
    taxa = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="taxaPct"]')
    latest_di_over = float(taxa.text.replace(',','.').replace('%',''))
    driver.close()
    return latest_di_over
```

But I've been told more than once that using requests+BeautifulSoup is better/faster than using selenium, so I was trying to move this script to that (if that isn't true, please explain why or how should I to make it faster).

When I try to do so (using the script below) I get the following response: `[<div class="valor" id="taxaPct"> </div>]` with no value inside the div. Why is that happening and what should I do to fix it?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

b3 = requests.get('http://www.b3.com.br/pt_br/')
b3_parsed = bs(response.text, 'html5lib')
print(b3_parsed.find_all('div', id='taxaPct'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is loaded dynamically via JavaScript. You can use `requests` module to simulate this call.

For example:

```
import json
import requests


url = 'https://www2.cetip.com.br/ConsultarTaxaDi/ConsultarTaxaDICetip.aspx'
data = requests.get(url).json()

print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

print()
print('Taxa :', data['taxa'])
```

Prints:

```
{
    "taxa": "2,15",
    "dataTaxa": "02/07/2020",
    "indice": "31.969,80",
    "dataIndice": "03/07/2020"
}

Taxa : 2,15
```